# Selinux permissions for Selenium, WebDriver, gecko, Firefox,

Tags: selenium, centos7, selinux

I have some Selenium WebDriver code working with Firefox, this runs with no problems on my MacBook and on Centos 7 if selinux is disabled.

I should enable selinux, but I then hit a permissions problem. As far as I can see there is a class

```
   org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber
```

which selects a port at random from a range determined by the environment, pragmatically that range seems potentially very large; say from 1024 to 32,000.

When Selinux is enabled the application is denied access to that port and so I get

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I believe that I should be able to:

1. use semanage to grant permissions to a range of ports
2. control the range of ports that selenium needs, seems like open up a wide range is a bit heavy handed.

I'd like to find a recipe for granting the permissions, and doing so in the least heavy-handed way. My major problem is that I'm overwhelmed by the selinux facilities, not sure of the proper way to enable the permissions I need.

Additional note: As @Edvin has said, in principle

```
 semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 1024-32000
```

would work. Unfortunately this is not permitted if other policies have opened ports such as 8080.

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9000-32000
```

will be permitted, but then leaves "islands" of ports that Selenium might select and fail. We cannot remove configurations for ports set by policies. Hence I'm still looking for selinux recipes or a way to control the selected port range.

For controlling the set of ports I'm seriously wondering whether to modify the PortProber class to select a limited range to work in (i never going to need even 100 different ports so a range of 1000 should be sufficient for my needs), and to report that range so that we can set the permissions accordingly. Is there a better approach?

Comment: I assume selenium use the `http_port_t` label as well like Firefox so `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 1024-32000` would open ports for all browser.

Comment: are you sure this is a port issue?  This error will also happen when Selenium can't launch the browser.  (Do you see the browser open?)

Comment: There are actually two separate errors: an inability to find a free port and then as you say an inability to launch Firefox. Both are cause by lacking selinux permissions. There is a quite extensive selinux policy required to allow Firefox policy to be launched.

Comment: @Edvin, thanks the setting of a port range does work, except that the range must not overlap any existing ports such as 8080.